# Graphics card for Blender - GeForce RTX 2060 Super

Tags: hardware

I'm buying new computer & there was a problem with graphics card. I want to buy "KFA2 GeForce RTX 2060 Super". Computer master helps me choose computer, but he saw somewhere in internet warning that Blender could crash because of this graphics card. Please tell me, will Blender work normally with this graphics card? Especially in Blender 2.79.

I don't know, maybe that warning was for those who has weak computer? Or does Blender not want to work with new graphics cards? If this data also helps answer my question, then my operating system was replaced with Windows 10 & also processor "AMD Ryzen 7 2700 OEM" & motherboard "ASRock Fatal1ty B450 Gaming K4" will be installed soon. At the moment, my graphics card "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970".

If this graphics card is not suitable for Blender, please advise which one is worth buying for new computer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's very pity that Blender 2.79 doesn't support new graphics cards.
But in general, RTX is good for Cycles or not? Or maybe I should look at some other version of graphics card?

Comment: [Hardware recommendations are off-topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic) on Blender's StackExchange. The RTX cards are supported in Blender 2.8x, but I believe the official release of 2.79b doesn't support them.

Comment: The reason is that 2.79b used an older version of the CUDA toolkit and its development was finished before the RTX cards were released. If you can't use Blender 2.8x for some reason, you would either have to compile 2.79b yourself, with a newer CUDA toolkit or download an unofficial build, e.g. from graphicall. The RTX cards are fully supported by Cycles in 2.8x

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Well, it's more convenient for me to work in 2.79.
But what if I add 2 graphics cards? To use my old graphics card for rendering in 2.79, and the new one in 2.8. Is this possible or not?
It seems my new motherboard to allow 2 graphics cards to be installed, but I don't know if GTX 970 & RTX 2060 Super will work together.

Comment: Sure that's possible.

Comment: It's good. Thank you so much for your help.